# ACS token request Plaintext vs. Signed

Tags: azure, acs

I'm trying to choose between Plaintext and Signed Token request methods for ACS (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee706734.aspx).

The only thing I came up with to differentiate these two methods is that Signed method provides an additional mitigation against an eavesdropper when someone tries to decrypt HTTPS traffic in order to get my password. In case of Signed it would be more difficult because other than decrypting HTTPS it needs also to break the signature (in order to learn the signing key).

Am I right that HTTPS is considered strong enough and should not require any additional things to make sure no one can read my messages?

What might be my arguments be in choosing Token request method for ACS between Plain text and Signed?

Comment: You're looking at documentation for ACS 1.0, which is no longer supported. Note the disclaimer on the top: "This content is outdated. For information on Windows Azure Access Control Service (ACS), see Access Control Service 2.0."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Plaintext and signed requests are both protected by the HTTPS transport. The tokens issued by ACS will conform to the web token format that has been configured for the relying party (scope), and the claims in the issued ACS token will contain the result of the claims generated by the transformation rules engine.

A plaintext request involves sending the user name and password of a service identity to ACS, with the scope indicating the relying party you wish to received an access token for. In this scenario the caller only needs to know the service identitity credentials in order to receive a token. In a plaintext request, the only claim available to the claims tranformation engine is a name identifier claim.

A signed request on the other hand is when the service consumer wants to provide a richer set of claims to the claims tranformation engine. The service consumer asserts a set of claims by creating an assertion that is encoded using the specified assertion format (typically SWT or JWT) and digitally signs the assertion using either a symmetric or asymmetric signing key.

SWT only supports symmetric signing using the HMAC SHA-256 algorithm, while JWT supports both symmetric and asymmetric signing algorithms. In this scenario the service consumer needs to be in possesion of the signing key that is used to digitally sign the assertion. ACS will verify the digital signature of the assertion to ensure the caller is trusted (they are in posession of the signing key) and that the assertion has not been tampered with. The claims transformation engine will then apply the relying party rules to generate an access token.

Use a plaintext request when you do not need a rich set of claims presented to the claims transformation engine (name identifier is sufficent) or when the service consumer does not support cryptographic signing of assertions.

Use a signed request when your claims transformation rules require multiple claims in order to perform output claim calculation, or when your service consumer already has a SAML assertion that it wishes to use.

See [OAuth WRAP](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-hardt-oauth-01) if you want a more complete description of the OAUTH WRAP protocol.